# How to use a for loop to display an image depending on a position in an index?

Tags: javascript, react-native

*This is inside a react-native project:*

I have a progress bar that has 10 positions, and each position as a possibility of three states - incomplete, active, complete. There is an image that corresponds to each of those states. I was thinking I could use a for loop that would look for the index number of the page, which I'll store in an object, and depending on the relationship between the position in the loop and and the index number, that would determine which image gets displayed. Something like this:

```
if the position in the loop > index number, display the incomplete image

if the position in the loop = index number, display the active image

if the position in the loop < index number, display the complete image
```

Beyond this, I'm not even sure on where to start.

Comment: Let me check if I understood: you have 10 screens and a progress bar with 10 positions. When the user is on a specific screen, you want the corresponding position on the progress bar to display an image, the previous positions display another and the further positions a different one. Is that correct?

Comment: @soutot yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class/component:

```
  state = {
    indexNum: 4, // arbitrary value
  }

  displayStatus(item) {
    if(item.id > this.state.indexNum){ // Incomplete
      return <View style={styles.progressPoint}><Text>I</Text></View>;
    }
    else if(item.id == this.state.indexNum){ // Active
      return <View style={styles.progressPoint}><Text>A</Text></View>;
    }
    else if(item.id < this.state.indexNum){ // Complete : you can use only 'else' here
      return <View style={styles.progressPoint}><Text>C</Text></View>;
    }

  }
```

In `render()` of your class/component:

```
    // Positions/Pages - these will serve as basis for .map - you can add more than 'id'
    const positions  = [{"id": 1},{"id": 2},{"id": 3},{"id": 4},{"id": 5},
                       {"id": 6},{"id": 7},{"id": 8},{"id": 9},{"id": 10}];
    return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
          {positions.map((item) => (
             this.displayStatus(item)
          ))}
       </View>
    );
```

Here's an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/BkdA1m2iz) of the above (based on the scope of your question) to get you started.

You can store the index number of the page in state and update this state at completion of each progress position. Note: if you are not using redux, you may need to pass/handle state (index number) on each page individually (depending on your navigation or components structure).

Comment: this got me pointed in the right direction and I was able to use this method in my project. Thanks for your help here!